# Find a piecewise definition of f that does not involve the absolute value function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I really have not clue on how to solve a problem like this. As you can see I got it wrong on my quiz and I need some clarification on the process of piecewise definitions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just stick with the definition:

$$|\color{grey}{\text{something}}|
=\begin{cases}
\color{grey}{\text{something}}&\text{if }\,\color{grey}{\text{something}}\geqslant0\\
-\color{grey}{\text{something}} &\text{if }\,\color{grey}{\text{something}}\lt0
\end{cases}.$$

In this case this $\color{grey}{\text{something}}$ is simply $\color{red}{x+7}$, so if we replace the above formula with it we will find:

$$|\color{red}{x+7}|=\begin{cases}\color{red}{x+7}&\text{if }\,\color{red}{x+7}\geqslant0\\-(\color{red}{x+7})&\text{if }\,\color{red}{x+7}\lt0\end{cases}.$$

We can simplify the above result to get:

$$|\color{}{x+7}|=\begin{cases}\color{}{x+7}&\text{if }\,\color{}{x}\geqslant-7\\-x-7&\text{if }\,\color{}{x}\lt-7\end{cases}.$$

Comment: So really the problem is just about understanding the definition and putting that into terms with the problem?

Comment: @MattButler Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

$$|x| = \begin{cases} x \hspace{5mm}\text{ if } x \geq 0 \\ -x \hspace{2mm}\text{ if } x < 0 \end{cases}$$

In words, the absolute value function makes the argument positive.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\vert x \vert = -x$ if $x < 0$ and $\vert x \vert = x$ if $x \geq 0$. Now substitute $x$ for $x+7$.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of x is defined by

$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
-x &&:  x \le 0\\
x && x>0
\end{aligned}
\right.$

Thus $|x-7|$ will be given by $x+7$ when $x>-7$ and by $-x-7$ when $x<-7$. The correct option would be a